# Programming in JavaScript with documentation in the IDE

Tags: javascript, eclipse, netbeans, ide, sublimetext2

i recently got shown the Phaser framework (found at phaser.io) and plan on using javascript with it. I'm very used to coding in java in eclipse which has code assist that lets you see the documentation of a method (parameters, description etc) and i want to know if there is a way to/how to do it with javascript. The framework comes with the documentation, but how can i link it to the class in an ide?

Comment: It probably depends on which IDE you are using. Some will index all the project files and provide code hinting based on what it finds. It also depends on how well documented the phaser code is, but it does look like it uses JavaDoc-esque code documentation, so maybe it will be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Check out TypeScript and Phaser.io.  This will give you full intellisense (auto-complete) in Visual Studio. This is exactly what you desire and the workflow works well as I have been using it for over 6 months.